# Moshi custom JsonAdapter unable to recognize type when using Retrofit QueryMap with Map<String, Any>

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, moshi

Retrofit interface

```
interface ApiService {
@GET("/api")
    suspend fun get(
        @QueryMap params: Map<String, Any>
    ): Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

Moshi custom adapter

```
class InstantJsonAdapter : JsonAdapter<Instant>() {
   override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: Instant?) {
    // ...
   }
}
```

When I call `apiService.get(params)` Moshi adapter is unable to recognize any parameter request of type `Instant` so it never calls `toJson()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As document of `QueryMap` says, QueryMap is converted through `retrofit.stringConverter()` which delegate to `Converter.Factory.stringConverter`.

And [MoshiConverterFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/1490e6b1f90c616e2283b098a2c8e51a88cc97c2/retrofit-converters/moshi/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/moshi/MoshiConverterFactory.java) only implements `responseConverter` and `requestConverter`, but not `stringConverter`. So if you use it, this is the reason.
You can implement your own converter factory and add it through `Retrofit.Builder.addConverterFactory()`.